# Visual Studio Code shows wrong typescript errors that disappear after file reopening

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, syntax-error, syntax-highlighting

Visual Studio Code shows strange typescript errors to me that are not real. It seems that VSC figures out that an syntax is wrong while I type (which can be true). But when I stop typing and the syntax is correct it still shows the wrong error, e.g.:

[[image]

If I close the file and open it again, the error does disappear. It happens to many different errors, not only this exact one.

Additionally if I do write a newline, the error seems to be "stuck" to line/column even though text has moved.

Comment: does this issue still happen for you? do you remember what version of VS Code you had installed at the time of writing this post?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot answer this anymore, I do not use typescript now and I cannot remember the version unfortunately. I had the latest version at all times I think though. So the version that was released before the time of the post would be a good hit