# vscode editor with flutter give incorrect errors

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

While typing in vscode with flutter, I get incorrect errors. it seems the editors has incorrect text and the problem is solved only when i close and open the file again

It happens all the time now.

I attached image presenting what happens when i am typing code in flutter.
There is nothing wrong with the function but i get errors

[image]

When I close and open the evetyhing is ok

[image]

Tried allready to reopen flutter, reinstall flutter, flutter clean, reinstall vscode, download the project again from github

Comment: I'm not sure if it'll work, but try this too: I've written [an answer about how to suppress linter errors/warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70831193/16136190). Looks like similar questions have been asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61059616/visual-studio-code-shows-wrong-typescript-errors-that-disappear-after-file-reope and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44045299/visual-studio-shows-code-errors-that-dont-exist.

Comment: GitHub issues on the known bug?: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/2047 and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/47386. There are [many Google results](https://www.google.com/search?q=error+disappears+only+after+reopening+vs+code) too, but none seem to convey "problem solved".